# I want to be able to drop files in full screen with react-dropzone while displaying other elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dropzone

Being a front end newbie, about typescript and css I am not sure I understand correctly. I would like to modify the code below to make all of the screens dropzone and also add the ability to preview images when they are dropped.
The following code uses react in typescript. It also uses react-dropzone.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';

function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<(File & {preview:string})[]>([]);
  const {getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone({
    accept: {
      'image/*': []
    },
    onDrop: acceptedFiles => {
      setFiles(acceptedFiles.map(file => Object.assign(file, {
        preview: URL.createObjectURL(file)
      })));
    }
  });

  const thumbs = files.map(file => (
    <div key={file.name} className="container mx-auto w-[600px] h-[400px]">
      <div>
        <img
          src={file.preview}
          onLoad={() => { URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview) }}
          className="container mx-auto w-[600px] h-[300px] object-contain"
        />
        <input className="container mx-autobg-gray-200 rounded-xl border p-5 m-10" />
      </div>
    </div>
  ));

  useEffect(() => {
    // Make sure to revoke the data uris to avoid memory leaks, will run on unmount
    return () => files.forEach(file => URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview));
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className="container mx-auto relative">
        <div {...getRootProps({className: 'dropzone  mx-auto bg-gray-200 rounded-xl shadow border p-8 m-10'})}>
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
        </div>
      <aside className="absolute">
        {thumbs}
      </aside>
    </section>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onDrop event on the div, example: `onDrop={(event) => onDropImage(event)}`
onDropImage would be the function to be called after the image is dropped, it could be implemented like this:

```
async function onDropImage(e: React.DragEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const img = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
}
```

To show the image on the screen you can use FileReader, example:

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onload = function() {
      // url is the variable where you save the url of the generated image
      url = fileReader.result;
   }
fileReader.readAsDataURL(img);
```

The function would look like this at the end:

```
async function onDropImage(e: React.DragEvent) {
         e.preventDefault();
         const img = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
         const fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function() {
            // url is the variable where you save the url of the generated image
            url = r.result;
        }
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(img);
}
```